# Oracle plsql syntax confusion?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, syntax

```
declare
    v_name varchar2(10) := 'bruce';
    v_name2 number;

begin
        case v_name
              when 'bruce' then DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('corr');
              else DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('incorrect');
        end case;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_name2);
end;




declare
    v_name varchar2(10) := 'bruce';
    num number(2) := 10;
begin
        num := case v_name
              when 'bruce' then 2
              else 12
        end;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(num);
end;
```

Getting confuse about semi colons. why in first code semicolon required and end case; keyword needed. But in 2nd code no semicolon & also just end;  I know in 2nd I am assigning value to variable, but so what ?

Answer (score 6):

case *statement* vs. case *expression*.

The [case *statement*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/CASE-statement.html#GUID-F4251A23-0284-4990-A156-00A92F83BC35) is for conditional execution of PL/SQL code:

```
    case v_name
          when 'bruce' then DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('corr');
          else DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('incorrect');
    end case;
```

The [case *expression*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-216F1B33-493F-4CDE-93BB-096BACA8523E) can be used both in PL/SQL and in regular SQL, and returns a value:

```
    num := case v_name
           when 'bruce' then 2
           else 12
           end;
```

Comment: Documentation: [case statement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/CASE-statement.html#GUID-F4251A23-0284-4990-A156-00A92F83BC35) vs [case expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-216F1B33-493F-4CDE-93BB-096BACA8523E)

Comment: @kfinity, great, I'll add it to my answer.